# Calculation of $H_0(\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology

I want to calculate the homology group $H_0(\mathbb{Q})$. This group counts path components, so I need to find them.

May somebody tell me what the paths $[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ are? I guess this are just the constant maps but I can't prove it.

Comment: A path that joins two different points would have a connected image, which is not possible in $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Q$ is totally disconnected so only continuous maps are the constant ones as continuous maps send connected sets to connected sets.

Comment: That's it. Thank you!